# What is the limit of $n\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

The textbook I'm reading gives no proof of the limit being 1 apart from a flimsy 0/0, and has covered only the "epsilon" and sandwich test for convergence to a particular limit.

Do not rearrange to turn $n$ into $\frac{1}{n}$, that is the source of the flimsy $0/0$ argument.

Comment: See [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}x=1.$$

Comment: But $why$? All I can see is 0/0...sandwich rule? Epsilons?

Comment: @You can find the explanation why this is true in just about any textbook on calculus...

Comment: There is nothing so far mentioned that implies that is anything more than naive intuition

Comment: @Nethesis Here, let me google that for you: http://www.ies-math.com/math/java/calc/LimSinX/LimSinX.html

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**  $\sin \left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \approx_{0} \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{2!}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \dfrac{1}{3!}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n^3}- ......\Rightarrow n\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \approx_0 1 - \dfrac{1}{2n} + \dfrac{1}{6n^2} - ....--$

Comment: That's...a lot more satisfactory

Comment: @Nethesis A warning for this answer: it uses more advanced mathematics than L'Hospital's rules. In effect, if you are using this, you are using a mathematical tool (the Taylor series) from which L'Hospital trivially follows, so if you don't yet know how to use L'Hospital, don't use this.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm not completely satisfied